# Changing Axis Names and Title of checkresiduals(} plots with ggplot2 package

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to change y-axis and change (remove completely) the title of this plot using `ggplot2` package.

```
## simulate ARIMA(1,0, 0)
set.seed(1)
ar1 <- arima.sim(n = 20, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
## do the plot
forecast::checkresiduals(forecast::auto.arima(ar1), main = "")
```

[image: Here is the plot]

I want to remove the title, `Residual from ARIMA(2,0,0) with zero mean` and also replace `df$y` with let's say `value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `checkresiduals` just runs `ggtsdisplay` on the `residuals` of your model. This plots a series of three ggplots in 3 separate grid viewports and returns the final plot as an object, so you can get the output you want with

```r
set.seed(1)
ar1 <- arima.sim(n = 20, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)

library(ggplot2)
library(forecast)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo

p <- ggtsdisplay(residuals(auto.arima(ar1)), plot.type = "histogram")

p <- p + labs(y = "value", x = "residuals")

print(p, vp = grid::viewport(layout.pos.row = 2, layout.pos.col = 2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Does not work: R version 4.3.0.